# Laravel Trying to access Sentinel user in service provider to share it with all views giving null

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, sentinel

I have a laravel 5.6 project and I am using Sentinel Cartalyst as authorization and authentication package.

I am trying to access the authenticated user at the level of Service Providers where I have created a custom service provider and registered it in config/app.php as follows:
App\Providers\AuxiliaryServiceProvider::class,
Now I am trying to do the following in its boot method:

```
use View;
use Sentinel;
class AuxiliaryServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
  public function boot(){
    //dd(Sentinel::getUser());//always gets null
     View::share([
         'loggedUser' => Sentinel::getUser()??null,
    ]);

  }
  public function register(){
        //
  }
}
```

Comment: And error you get?

Comment: there is no particular error, it just I am [not able to access] the authenticated user through Sentinel -  It seems it is not yet checked at this level of AppServiceProvider.
I need to access the authenticated user to be able to pass it to all blade views i.e. Share it with all views so I can get its properties at the blade view level.
My Objective is to [Share the authenticated user] in all blade views but [not through the controller] that calls the view which of course works fine but on individual views.